# Java - class name in method declaration where the return type should be

Tags: java, class, methods

I am working on some code where there is a method that looks like this:

```
    public static ProcessorClass getProcessor(String x, int y) {
     return(var);
    }
```

From what I remember the way this is written the "ProcessorClass" is a return type but what does that mean. The "ProcessorClass" is the class that the method is currently in. I am confused in what this means.

Comment: It means it returns a `ProcessorClass` instance. There's nothing wrong with a method on a class returning an instance of the same class.

Answer (score 7):

Check this example, which is an implementation of the Singleton pattern:

```
public class Ploop
{
    private final int x;
    private static Ploop instance = null;

    public int getX()
    {
        return x;
    }

    public static Ploop getInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null) instance = new Ploop();
        return instance;
    }

    private Ploop()
    {
        x = 0;
    }
}
```

In this case, the `getInstance()` function is the only way to get a new `Ploop` object.  If the constructor were `public`, then there would be two ways, `new Ploop()` and `Ploop.getInstance()`.

Because the `getInstance()` only instantiates `Ploop` once, there can only ever be one instance of `Ploop`.  (Barring unusual ways of instantiating an object, like through reflection...)

Another way to make use of this pattern is to allow a class to use the Builder pattern to instantiate itself in phases.

Does this make anything clearer?

Comment: Is there a reason why you would want to create the method over the constructor?

Comment: One reason would be if you're implementing a singleton.  Then the constructor is only called once, and the function keeps returning the same instance.  Usually (always?) a singleton class has a private constructor so that it can enforce that there is only one instance.

Comment: Another reason might be that the class builds itself (as in the builder pattern) and the `build()` method returns the built instance.

Answer (score 1):

When a method uses a class name as its return type, the class of the type of the returned object must be either a subclass of, or the exact class of, the return type.

Suppose that you have a class hierarchy in which ImaginaryNumber is a subclass of java.lang.Number, which is in turn a subclass of Object, as illustrated below.

```
                        Object
                          |
                        Number
                          |
                     ImaginaryNumber
```

Now suppose that you have a method declared to return a Number:

```
public Number returnANumber() {
    ...
}
```

The returnANumber method can return an ImaginaryNumber but not an Object. ImaginaryNumber is a Number because it's a subclass of Number. However, an Object is not necessarily a Number — it could be a String or another type.

You can override a method and define it to return a subclass of the original method, like this:

```
public ImaginaryNumber returnANumber() {
    ...
}
```

This technique, called covariant return type, means that the return type is allowed to vary in the same direction as the subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, a return type can be anything, if a method returns something. You can return the instance of the same class where the method is defined.

`ProcessorClass` here is a return type. You are returning an instance of the class.

Eg.

```
class ProcessorClass {
 public ProcessorClass someMethod() {
  return new ProcessorClass();
 }
}
```

Here the method is returning the same type as the class.

```
class XYZ {
 pubic ProcessorClass anotherMethod() {
  return new ProcessorClass();
 }
}
```

Here the method is returning the above class type.